# externally supported module, setting X kernel taint flag

Tags: kernel, drivers

Does this mean a driver is not from the original OS-distributor, the kernel becomes a tainted kernel?

What does 'X' mean?

I didn't see an explanation for 'x'

ref:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the latest version of that document: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html

> ```
> Bit   Log     Number  Reason that got the kernel tainted
> ...
> 16    _/X     65536   auxiliary taint, defined for and used by distros
> ```

Its C name is `TAINT_AUX`; As its definition suggests, it's not set by any code in the vanilla kernel.